# Cartesian equation for conchoid of Nicomedes?

Tags: algebraic-curves, plane-curves

Consider a rectangular cartesian system and let $b, d, r\in\mathbb R$ such that $d\neq 0$ and $r>0$. The parameter $d$ is allowed to vary, however $b$ and are fixed once they are given.

I'm trying to find the cartesian equation of the curve which consists of all points $(x, y)$ in the plane which are the intersection between the circle centered at $(d, 0)$ with radius $r$ and the straight line through $(0, -b)$ and $(d, 0)$.

Well, the points $(x, y)$ should be such that:

$$(x, y)=(1-t)\cdot (0, -b)+t\cdot (d, 0)$$

for some $t\in \mathbb R$ and

$$(x-d)^2+y^2=r^2.$$

From the first condition, it would follow

$$x=t\cdot d\ \textrm{and}\ y=(t-1)\cdot b.$$

Hence,
$$y=\left(\frac{x}{d} -1\right) b=\frac{b}{d}(x-d).$$
Then,

$$r^2=(x-d)^2+\frac{b^2}{d^2}(x-d)^2$$
which implies

$$r^2 d^2=(b^2+d^2)(x-d)^2.$$

There is also an expression involving $y$. In fact, using

$$(x-d)=\frac{d}{b} y$$

it follows

$$\frac{d^2}{b^2} y^2+y^2=r^2$$

and then

$$b^2r^2=(b^2+d^2)y^2$$.

However, I'd like to get a single expression involving $x$ and $y$, since I want to see the curve as the zero set of a polynomial in the variables $x$ and $y$.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: The fourth displayed equation says $y=\frac{b}{d}(x-d)$. The antepenultimate (second-from-last equation) says you are using $(x-d)=\frac{b}{d}y$. Shouldn't that be $(x-d)=\frac{d}{b}y$?

Comment: That was a typo l! Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation of the line is $$\frac{x}{d}-\frac{y}{b}=1$$ and the equation of the circle is $$(x-d)^2+y^2 = r^2$$

From the first equation $$d=\frac{b\,x}{b+y}$$

Substitute in the second equation to get

$$\left(x-\frac{b\,x}{b+y}\right)^2+y^2=r^2$$

which simplifies to $$y^2(x^2+(b+y)^2) = r^2(b+y)^2$$